# Google Analytics V3 - Authentication Java

Tags: java, google-analytics

This is my code to access Google Analytics API to upload Audiences. But when i tried to execute I am getting "401 : Login Required".I have provided correct Client Id and Client Secret. Is there any other object do i need to populate in GoogleCredential ? What Am i missing ?

```
public class TestGoogleAnalytics {
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Calling Analytics";
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException{
try {
  File file = new File("/home/hariprasath/test.csv");
  System.out.println(file.canWrite());
  Analytics analytics = createAnalytics();
  InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream",
    new FileInputStream(file));
  mediaContent.setLength(file.length());
  System.out.println("Test" + file.length());
  Uploads uploads = analytics.management().uploads().list("accountId",
      "webPropertyId", "customDataSourceId").execute();
} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
  System.err.println("There was a service error: "
      + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
      + e.getDetails().getMessage());
}  }  
private static Analytics createAnalytics() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException{
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
HttpExecuteInterceptor interseptor;
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setClientSecrets("clientId", "clientSecret")
    .set
    .build();
// Construct the Analytics service object.
return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

}

}